# Yocto QT6 Could not find CMAKE_AR

Tags: qt, cmake, yocto, bitbake

Trying to build a QT based app for yocto.  I started a new project in QT Creator for a QtQuick CMake based project.  I only edited the qml files to mock out the rough UI I wanted and tested it on my desktop.  I started a new Yocto kirkstone project and it built core-image-weston correctly once.  But when I added my project, Bitbake exits during it's configure stage with:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| CMake Error at toolchain.cmake:11 (find_program):
|   Could not find CMAKE_AR using the following names:
|   aarch64-poky-linux-gcc-ar
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:131 (include)
|   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

The only lines I have changed from the default local config are:

```
MACHINE = "raspberrypi3-64"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " usw"

QT_EDITION = "opensource"
```

Commenting out IMAGE_INSTALL for my project it will proceed with the build and finish a running image. My bblayers with my project (usw) at the end:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta-poky \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta-qt6 \
  /mnt/MediumData/yocto/usw/poky/meta-usw \
  "
```

usw.bb:

```
#summary and license

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI = ""

S = "${WORKDIR}"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1"

inherit qt6-cmake

SRC_URI += "file://main.cpp file://Main.qml file://WatchItem.qml file://CMakeLists.txt"
```

The CMake is still the default one created by Qt Creator but for completeness sake it is:

```
﻿cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(usw VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appusw
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appusw
    URI usw
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml WatchItem.qml
)

set_target_properties(appusw PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appusw
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

install(TARGETS appusw
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

Comment: Setting `INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS` to 1 removes the compiler from sysroot... are you sure that you need this setting?